# How can I include all files in current directory excluding file itself

Tags: php, function, include

I wrote mini function for including all php files in directory

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

How can I include all files in current directory excluding file itself (in which located function) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help. You should just get the current script file name and compare to the items from the array:

```
$this_file = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename)
{
    if ($filename !== $this_file) {
        include $filename;
    }
}
```

More details:

- [`basename()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php),
- [`$_SERVER` array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php),

Comment: Worth to mention: Its not said, that the current script is the called script

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
  if (realpath($filename) !== __FILE__) include $filename;
}
```

or maybe

```
foreach (array_diff(array_map('realpath',glob("*.php")), array(__FILE__) as $filename) {
  include $filename;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a mistake - `$filename` will be eg. "`main.php`", but `__FILE__` may be "`/main.php`" and then comparison will fail.

Comment: You're right. I assumed, that the result of `glob()` contains absolute paths, but it doesn't. The second solution is "not that nice" anymore, but it should work